# Allow only Selenium access the page

Tags: unit-testing, testing, selenium, phpunit

Is there any reliable way to allow only Selenium to access the site?

When I use `$this->open($url)` from the PHPUnit's SeleniumTestCase this makes a regular request to the server. How can I force this method to send some additional headers?

Comment: If you're running your Selenium tests against an instance of your application uniquely deployed for QA you shouldn't really have an issue with security. How is it you actually need to prevent access for a site that's undergoing testing like this? Just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add additional headers have a look at the selenium.addCustomRequestHeader([key],[value]); function.

Comment: And how to do this from PHP? Looks like PHPUnit does not support this method.

Comment: Hmm looks like PHP-Unit hasn't been updated since 2005 and as a result is missing a fair bit of new selenium functionality, I mistakenly assumed that it would have the same functionality as the Java bindings.

A potential option would be to override the PHP-Unit function that calls Open and inject some headers using the PHP header function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), I would need to investigate this some more though.

Answer (score 3):

You could add auth to your .htaccess for that site/subfolder and preprend the simple auth user@password to your url before each request.

Reading about simple auth with .htaccess and .htpasswd:

http://www.htaccesstools.com/htaccess-authentication/

Comment: And how can I password protect an URI (which is actually handled by mod_rewrite), not a real, existing file using `.htaccess` rules?

Answer (score 0):

I would allow access to the site only from the Selenium machine's IP, i.e. via .htaccess or web server config directives.